# Cross-platform collation and ctype

Tags: postgresql

I code on a Windows machine but use a Linux machine in production.

The PostgreSQL `lc_collate` and `lc_ctype` are OS-dependent, which presents a few problems.

When I create a database (e.g. `create database db with encoding 'UTF8' lc_collate 'en_US.UTF-8' lc_ctype 'en_US.UTF-8'`), I have to detect the OS and specify the appropriate values, which is troublesome.

The biggest problem is when copying the production database to the development machine using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. There is no easy way to replace these values when dumping/restoring.

What is the best way to workaround these problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is annoying.

PostgreSQL has recognized that using the OS collations was maybe not the best idea, so they introduced ICU collations recently which are operating system independent.

Unfortunately, these cannot be used with `CREATE DATABASE` yet.

Collations cause little trouble when using `pg_dump`/`pg_restore`.
All you have to do is create the database at the target system using an existing collation and then import the dump into that database.